# SQL Server Virtual Network Name Change Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2012, high-availability, windows-cluster

I am in the process of configuring a two-node failover cluster for a migration project. We are transitioning a stand-alone SQL Server to a cluster.

**Environment:**
2x nodes with Windows Server 2012 R2 SP1
SQL Version: SQL Server 2008 SP1

The Windows FCI is configured, validated and SQL Failover Cluster is installed and working. No issues there. The part I am having issue with is when attempting to modify the SQL Server Virtual Network Name. I follow the steps outlined here: [SQL Network Name Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178083%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) .

**Error Received:**

```
There was an error saving properties for 'SQL Server'.
Failed to execute control code 20971654
Error Code: 0x8007000d The data is invalid.
```

Has anyone encountered this before? All information I have come across concerning renaming the SQL Server Network name has made it seem like a fairly trivial process, but I cannot get it to happen in my setup. Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

**Background on why I want to do this:**
The existing SQL Server is pretty much the heart & soul of all our major business operations. There are concerns with not using the same server name after the migration. I have workarounds that involve the use of DNS CNames and/or adding a secondary "OR" dependency IP address to the SQL Network Name Cluster Resource, which would be the IP address currently in use by the SQL server being migrated. We would add the dependency after taking the old server offline. This has been tested and works, but the cleanest setup for me would be to modify the SQL Server Virtual Network Name, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I should answer my own question as I believe the issue lies in user error :)

However, I was following some apparently bad advice, so maybe this will clear up the issue for someone else in the future if they fall into the same trap.

**Original Method I was using to modify SQL Server Network Name:**

1. Failover Cluster Manager (Win 2012) -> SQL Server Role -> click resources tab -> Bring Server Name Resource offline.
2. Right Click SQL Server Resource and select Properties
3. On the Properties tab modify VirtualServerName value
4. Click OK and receive error specified in question above.

**Correct Way:**

1. Failover Cluster Manager (Win 2012) -> SQL Server Role -> click resources tab -> Bring Server Name Resource offline.
2. Right Click on Server Name Resource for SQL Server Network Name and select Properties
3. On the General tab modify the DNS Name to the desired new name for the SQL Server Virtual Network Name

After bringing all the resources back online the virtual network name is successfully changed and accessible.